# Instasharp C# api is there any skip parameter?

Tags: c#, instagram

I'm using the api wrapper Instasharp to get all of my pictures. Is there any skip parameter for this? At the moment i have the following url to get my pictures:

"https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/{3}/media/recent?client_id={0}&count={1}";

Answer (score 0):

Per IG's [documentation](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/), there doesn't seem to be any "skip" parameter.  You'll need to use "min_id" and "max_id" to paginate through the IG data calls.

http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/tags/

IG info, as of 8/6/13:
GET /tags/tag-name/media/recent

Get a list of recently tagged media. Note that this media is ordered by when the media was tagged with this tag, rather than the order it was posted. Use the max_tag_id and min_tag_id parameters in the pagination response to paginate through these objects.